# why there is '.' and '..' when we scandir function

Tags: php

When we use scandir function.it will display the all the files and directories inside the directory,which we pass in the scandir function as argument.
But it also add two more element `.` and `..`

I want to know why these two element is showing?

Comment: It doesn't __add__ those elements, they're already there as filesystem entries

Comment: Use `array_values(array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.')))` or `array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'))` to remove the `.` and `..` from the results. `array_values` makes the index start from 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are directories. The . is the current directory and the .. is the parent directory
You can try cd into this directories like this:

cd .

Answer (score 5):

`'.'` is current directory

`'..'` is parent directory